# ¿Cómo soluciono el error org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec?

Tags: java, netbeans, maven, exec-maven-plugin

he intentado programar un juego en java siguiendo el siguiente tutorial:
https://youtu.be/vnqb9vdaxwA?si=K9fNp4p4BApSTOZP
me sale el siguiente error al intentar ejecutar:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec
> (default-cli) on project bacterybattlebeta: Command execution failed.:
> Process exited with an error: -1073741819 (Exit value: -1073741819) ->[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
> [Help 1]
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

tengo la teoria que descargue unos plugins por error y por eso sale esto, si saben como ayudarme estaria muy agradecido.

Comment: falta el resto de la traza donde de hecho viene el error